# While consuming web API with api key, it gives following error - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-403

While consuming web API with api key, I get this error

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

This is my code:

```
private void Getdata()
{
    var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("my api url");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "x-api-key" "mykeyvalue");
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    try
    {
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                txtresult.Text = reader.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException e)
    {
        txtresult.Text = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: This is a server problem, most probably with your authorization. We can't help you with it. As the error states, the **server** forbids access (therefore _403 Forbidden_).

Comment: Thanks @NikxDa for information. Please let me know my code implementation is proper or something is missing?

Comment: Are you sure the header is correct? Because`"x-api-key" "mykeyvalue"` generates `x-api-keymykeyvalue`

Comment: Thanks @mjcs. How to add API key authorization in header?

Comment: @Abhijeet You will have to check the documentation for the API server but my guess is that it's something like this `request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "mykeyvalue");`

Comment: @mjcs Thank you so much. request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "mykeyvalue") - this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the add header to:

`request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "mykeyvalue");`

Because `x-api-key` is the name of the header used to do API key authorization in this case.